# How to access Shopify app owned metafields in theme extension liquid files?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am having trouble finding the liquid app object. Shopify mentions about this object here https://shopify.dev/changelog/new-app-liquid-object but when we click the link within it(https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#app) to go to the object nothing appears. I am trying to access App-owned metafields in the theme app extension liquid file. Even if I mention app object in the liquid file it throws an error(Undefined object "app"). Can somebody please let me know how I can access App owned metafields in Theme Extension?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Using `{{ app }}` I was able to get AppDrop however my successes end there. Anyone knows what properties appdrop has?

Answer (score 1):

> Even if I mention app object in the liquid file it throws an error(Undefined object "app")

The 'new-app-liquid-object' you mention was only added this year in April 2022, so my first thought is to [check the Shopify API version](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/how-do-i-find-my-shopify-api-version/td-p/567119) that's currently in use incase it's earlier than than April 2022 and hence the feature doesn't exist yet. This seems like the most likley issue.

The  method `.metafields` can be queried on a number of different object types, so the following should all work: `product.metafields`, `customer.metafields`, `order.metafields` and yes `app.metafields` as well. (In [the metafield docs](https://shopify.dev/changelog/new-app-liquid-object) click 'map' on the example code to the right see what I mean)

From [their example](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#metafield-accessing-metafields-of-type-list) you'd access the value of an item like this:
`product.metafields.information.pickup_locations.value.last`

As [the announcement says](https://shopify.dev/changelog/new-app-liquid-object) "A new Liquid app object is available for use within the context of **theme app extensions** and **app proxies**. " [emphasis added]

**Which "app" are you trying to access?**
Actually can you give a more tangible example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Imagine you are building an app block. The given app has a private metafields with values that you don't want to mix with regular metafields thus polluting the store metafields. Ideally you would try to access these metafields in my-app-block.liquid file to display the "hidden" value. I guess this is what this feature is supposed to do

Comment: I've had more of a poke around, could Metafield filters help? "Metafield filters output metafield data from a metafield object within a relevant HTML element, or as a plain string." https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters#metafield-filters

Comment: Do you mean that by using the `metafield_tag` filter we could try to access app's private metafield? This is interesting idea

Answer (score -1):

You can find more info on app owned meta fields here
[App-owned metafields](https://shopify.dev/apps/metafields/app-owned)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Comment: Where exactly this link provides the info on how to access these fields in liquid?